# Unity Share Score Facebook only takes link and image, not name, caption and description

Tags: c#, facebook, unity-game-engine, feed, caption

Im triying to share on facebook a score obtained in a game developed in Unity using the next C# code:

```
Application.OpenURL("https://www.facebook.com/dialog/feed?"+
 "app_id="+AppID+ "&link="+Link+ "&picture="+Picture+
 "&name="+ReplaceSpace(Name)+ "&caption="+ReplaceSpace(Caption)+
 "&description="+ReplaceSpace(Description)+
 "&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Ffacebook.com");
```

When I press the share button in game, facebook shows me the feed dialog which is complete. All is correctly filled, but when I press share button to confirm, only post the url, not was added name, caption and description neither.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you post the URL that is opened in the browser? Another thing that's interesting is that you ask about Name, Caption and Description, all which go through your ReplaceSpace method. Are you sure the ReplaceSpace method returns what you expect?

Comment: The URL appears be fine, I change the text fields by "Test" and facebook shows me the dialog prepared to shows "Test" but when press on share only publish the google play link.

Answer (score 1):

ReplaceSpace(string s) may not be enough (if it does what the name is suggesting), you should consider using [WWW.EscapeURL(string s)](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/WWW.EscapeURL.html) which will escape all relevant characters.

e.g.:

```
Application.OpenURL("https://www.facebook.com/dialog/feed?" +
 "app_id=" + WWW.EscapeURL(AppID) + 
 "&link=" + WWW.EscapeURL(Link) +
 "&picture=" + WWW.EscapeURL(Picture) +
 "&name=" + WWW.EscapeURL(Name) + 
 "&caption=" + WWW.EscapeURL(Caption) +
 "&description=" + WWW.EscapeURL(Description) +
 "&redirect_uri=" + WWW.EscapeURL("https://facebook.com"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Inm the case of a link to iTunes or google play facebook does not show the parameters you show:

> Note: If your app share links to the iTunes or Google Play stores, or
>   to a Facebook profile or page, we do not post any images or
>   descriptions that you specify in the share with the parameters below.
>   Instead we post some app information we scrape from the app store or
>   Facebook page directly with the Webcrawler. This may not include
>   images. To preview a link share to iTunes or Google Play, enter your
>   URL into the URL Debugger.

Quote from the [documentation section "parameters"](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/reference/feed-dialog/v2.5)